# Python help needed arrays

Tags: python, arrays, nested-loops

I'm new to python and I had a simple script for importing some excel file data into my SQL server. The vendor we get the data from changed the format and its no longer going to work with my script.

The excel file contains repeating rows of Employee Name, Location, and Hours. I can currently loop through these rows, but struggling with how to go about summing up the hours for each employee and location.

Example excel file

```
Test User1, ABQ, 2
Test User1, ABQ, 4
Test User1, ABQ, 5
Test User1, BOS, 2
Test User1, BOS, 3
Test User2, MSP, 1
Test User2, MSP, 5
```

Was thinking of output being in some array like the following
Users array where

```
Users[0] = [Test User1, ABQ, 11]
Users[1] = [Test User1, BOS, 5]
Users[2] = [Test User2, MSP, 6]
```

Steps I was thinking.

1. create the array
2. check if employee and location exist in array
3. if not exists, then add employee name, location, and hours to array
4. else if employee and location exist then add hours to existing array hours

Existing code

```
# reading excel file in with pandas. jf is custom class for opening and reading the excel file into jf.techLog
    for i in jf.techLog.index:
        log = jf.techLog.loc[i].copy()
        # log variable contains the current excel sheet row data
        employees = [log['Technician'], log['City'], log['TotalHours']]
```

Comment: You can use a dict keeping the the first two columns as key, and add the value. Later you can convert the dict as array if you would like.